# Update Json filed in Prisma directly

Tags: database, prisma

Suppose we have a Json field in Prisma that I want to add new data to Json field that have old data, in regular method first I find the field then I update the Json data, then I update the field with new Json.

So, is there any way to update directly the Json field that has old data with new data in one command? (Without finding in first)

used libs:
Prisma 4.10.1
Nextjs 13.1.6
Mysql 8.0.3

I tried `push` and `merge` but they inserted db as key also!

```
await prisma.thetable.update({
    where: {
        user_id: id,
    },
    data: {
        theJsonField: {
            merge: {
                amount: 26
            }
        },
        otherIntField: {
            decrement: 7
        }
    }
})
```

in the db:
[image]

Comment: In your example how should the JSON field look like after updating? Do you want to append data to your json field?

Comment: Yes I want to append new data to old data, then update the db

Comment: The most straightforward approach would be to get the JSON field first, update the JSON object locally and then set the updated object. Also, I think this reference can be helpful: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-fields/working-with-json-fields#writing-to-a-json-field

Comment: @NurulSundarani I wish to have a function like 'increment' to update it directly